# List item long press (Android 4.0, Contextual action bar)

Tags: android, android-4.0-ice-cream-sandwich

I have a ListView in my app and I want to show contextual action bar on a long press gesture like in design best practices for ICS

http://developer.android.com/design/patterns/selection.html

is there any default way to do that? Or i need to write my own custom action bar?

Answer (score 4):

so, I think here's a good tutoiral:
http://www.vogella.com/articles/Android/article.html#tutorial_contextualmenu

and the very good one is here
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/menus.html